# MUIDataTable: In react application viewColumns options how to display the Checkbox List for column vertically

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I have a MUI Table Implementation such that the options object viewColumns is set to true, which is supposed to display the popper to choose the columns to be displayed in vertical list of checkbox as shown below:

[image]

, but I am getting it horizontally as displayed in screenshot below:

[image]

The options to be passed in MUIDataTable components is defined as:

```
const options = {
      filter: true,
      filterType: "dropdown",
      print: false,
      viewColumns: true,
      selectableRows: false,
      onRowClick: (rowData) => {
        console.log("RowClicked->", rowData);
      },
      responsive: "stacked",
      fixedHeaderOptions: {
        xAxis: false,
        yAxis: true,
      },
    };
```

columns defines as:

```
export const DEAL_GRID_COLUMNS = [
  {
    name: "someReference",
    label: "Some Reference",
    options: {
      filter: true,
      sort: true,
    },
  },
  {
    name: "businessTeam",
    label: "Business Teams",
    options: {
      filter: true,
      sort: true,
    },
  },
  {
    name: "keyContact",
    label: "Key Contact Lead",
    options: {
      filter: true,
      sort: true,
    },
  },
.....
.....
.....
.....
];
```

and the component is consumed as

```
<MUIDataTable data={gridData} columns={DEAL_GRID_COLUMNS} options={options} />
```

here `gridData` is recieved from Api response

Answer (score 1):

I made sample example using your `options` and I found `viewColumns` popper as vertical. I assume there is mui-datatable version issue. FYI, I am using `"mui-datatables": "^2.14.0"`

**Here is the example:**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";
import axios from 'axios';

export default function DataTable() {
    const [posts, setPost] = useState([]);
    let signal = axios.CancelToken.source();

    useEffect(() => {
        let isSubscribed = true;
        axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`, {
            cancelToken: signal.token,
        })
            .then(res => {
                const posts = res.data;
                setPost(posts);
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
        return function cleanup() {
            isSubscribed = false;
            signal.cancel('Api is being canceled');
        }
    }, []);

    const columns = ["id", "title", "body"];

    const options = {
        filter: true,
        filterType: "dropdown",
        print: false,
        viewColumns: true,
        selectableRows: 'none',
        onRowClick: (rowData) => {
            console.log("RowClicked->", rowData);
        },
        responsive: "stacked",
        fixedHeaderOptions: {
            xAxis: false,
            yAxis: true,
        },
    };

    return (
        <MUIDataTable
            title={"Posts"}
            data={posts}
            columns={columns}
            options={options}
        />
    );
}
```

**You can check this output screen**

[image]

Comment: I am using the same version... whats your  "@material-ui/core": "^4.10.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2", versions??? Mine is these...

Comment: you can see the picture where viewColumns is coming vertically. what is the version of mui-datatables for you?

Comment: I am on 2.14.0 as well, i will tried elimination few columns with thought that of too much columns, but that also didnt changed anything

Comment: can u please run my sample code on your environment and check if it is ok or not?

Comment: My id is a string for example {'id': '123dea-qweasd'}, how can I generate an id with the Lenght of my options Array?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by overriding its maxWidth as

```
MuiPopover: {
    paper: {
      maxWidth: "16%",
    },
  }
```